# Erro java.io.FileNotFoundException com FileInputStream

Tags: java, android

Estou pegando um arquivo de video dentro do meu aplicativo.

```
lnlOpenGalery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), 0);
            }
        });
```

No onActivityResult pego o caminho da URL e coloco em um player de reprodução... isso funciona perfeitamente, o prbolema meu está sendo em pegar esse caminho e colocar dentro de um FileInputStream, pois preciso converter esse arquivo em Bytes.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(data.getData()));
           videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
           MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
           mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
           mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
           videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
           videoView.start();
           try {
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(String.valueOf(uri)));
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }


}
```

Porque que no FileInputStream não consegue achar essa URL do meu video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na forma como você está acessando esses diretórios/arquivos. Observe que um objeto **URI** quando é convertida para **String** fica dessa forma:

> **content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/20**

E quando se utiliza o getPath() de um objeto **URI** fica assim

> **/document/20**

Se você perceber, quando utilizar um **new File(String.valueOf(uri)).exists()** sempre vai retornar **false**.

> É boa ideia criar uma lógica para receber esses dados quando isso
> retornar **verdadeiro**.

Então a forma correta de acessar o arquivo e diretório seria dessa forma:

> **FileInputStream fis = getContext().contentResolver().openInputStream(uri);**

E o código completo ficaria (Sou do kotlin, fique atento para erros de sintaxe):

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(data.getData()));
           videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
           MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
           mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
           mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
           videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
           videoView.start();
           try {
              FileInputStream fis = getContext().contentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }


}
```

E se você preferir, poderia economizar recursos fazendo esses ajustes aqui:

1. Substitua isso

   ```
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(data.getData()));
       videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
   ```

Por

```
       videoView.setVideoURI(data.getData());
```

Criar um método utilitário para converter Uri para bytes. Seria algo assim:

```
    public byte[] readBytes(Uri uri) throws IOException {
      // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
      InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
       int bufferSize = 1024;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
       int len = 0;
       while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
       }

      // and then we can return your byte array.
      return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

E o que você gostaria de fazer seria apenas assim...

> **readBytes(data.getData());**

Comment: com pequenas adaptações funcionou perfeitamente. valeu